# How do I set the selection color of the moreNavigationController table?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

How do I set the cell selection color for the view controller listed in the More of a tab view controller on iOS 6?

The default is blue, which looks terrible with an app that uses a non-default color. I'd like to set it to a custom color, if possible, but setting it to grey would do.

[image]

This problem is specific to iOS 6 because on iOS 7 a grey selection color is used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can update cell selection color for the view controller listed in the More of a tab view controller on by creating custom datasource for MoreNavigationController.

I have created an sample project which might help - https://github.com/deepthit/CustomizeMoreNavigationController.git

In the custom data source object we can override cellForRowAtIndexPath method to set selectedbackgroundView for a cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [originalDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Set background color
  UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
  background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  background.backgroundColor  = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.backgroundView = background;

  // Set selected background color
  UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
  selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  selectionColor.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Very thorough. Thank you. :)